# Search Text on Image in vaadin

Tags: pdf, vaadin7

I designed a Document Viewer that displays the PDF pages in image format.

I need to implement search functionality on this image formatted pages. When the user enters a term in the search textfield, the term has to be highlighted wherever it is present in the image. This is the code I have tried.

```
private VerticalLayout buildMainVerticalLayout()
{
    mainVerticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    SwingController controller = new SwingController();

    SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);

    JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();

    controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
            new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(
                    controller.getDocumentViewController()));

    JFrame applicationFrame = new JFrame();
    applicationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    applicationFrame.getContentPane().add(viewerComponentPanel);

    controller.openDocument("test.pdf");

    applicationFrame.pack();
    applicationFrame.setVisible(true);

    DocumentSearchController searchController =
            controller.getDocumentSearchController();

    for (String term : terms) {
        searchController.addSearchTerm(term, false, false);
    }

    Document document = controller.getDocument();

    ArrayList<WordText> foundWords;
    for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < document.getNumberOfPages();
         pageIndex++) {
        foundWords = searchController.searchPage(pageIndex);
        System.out.println("Page " + pageIndex);
        if (foundWords != null){
            for (WordText wordText : foundWords){
                System.out.println("    found hit: " +    wordText.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    return mainVerticalLayout;
}
```

But the output showing an error. I have tried with many possibilities. It is just opening the editor, but the PDF isn't loading.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please provide some relevant code, examples of what you have tried, and more detailed explanation. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Please include details of the error too.

Comment: Its displaying a dialog box with the following message: `Icepdf couldnot open the specified file at test.pdf. The file may be corrupt or not a supported file type`.  I tried with other example pdf files, but still the same error is being displayed.

Comment: Got the solution.. Worked on it with few examples from online and finally got the desired output.